# Negative Spacing - Align Environment

Tags: spacing, align

I am writing the following optimization model:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,onecolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    & \mathcal{L} \left( \boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{r}^{U}, \boldsymbol{r}^{D}; \tilde{\boldsymbol{g}} \right) = \max_{\substack{\boldsymbol{a}^{G}, \boldsymbol{a}^{L}, \boldsymbol{\beta}, \boldsymbol{\gamma}, \\ \underline{\boldsymbol{\pi}}, \overline{\boldsymbol{\pi}}, \underline{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}, \overline{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}}} ~ \sum_{b \in \mathscr{N}} \beta_{b} \left( D_{b} - \tilde{g}_{b} \right) - \sum_{l \in \mathscr{L}} \overline{F}_{l} \left( \underline{\pi}_{l} + \overline{\pi}_{l} \right) + \sum_{i \in \mathscr{I}} \left[ \underline{\sigma}_{i} \left( a_{i}^{G} \left( p_{i} - r_{i}^{D} \right) \right) - \overline{\sigma}_{i} \left( a_{i}^{G} \left( p_{i} + r_{i}^{U} \right) \right) \right]  \label{eq01:LOL_Func_SL} \\
    & \hspace{2.20cm} \text{subject to:} \notag \\
    & \hspace{2.20cm} \beta_{b} + \underline{\sigma}_{i} - \overline{\sigma}_{i} \leq 0, && \hspace{-4.50cm} \forall ~ b \in \mathscr{N}, i \in \mathscr{I}_{b}; \label{eq03:LOL_Func_SL} \\
    & \hspace{2.20cm} \beta_{to(l)} - \beta_{fr(l)} + \gamma_{l} + \underline{\pi}_{l} - \overline{\pi}_{l} = 0, && \hspace{-4.50cm} \forall ~ l \in \mathscr{L}; \label{eq04:LOL_Func_SL}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want to align all $\forall$ operators but since the objective function is too big, I need to use a negative "\hspace". Is there a way around?[image]

Answer (score 3):

With `alignat` and small manual tweaking:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,times,onecolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

    \begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
\mathcal{L} \left(\boldsymbol{p}, \boldsymbol{r}^{U}, \boldsymbol{r}^{D}; \tilde{\boldsymbol{g}} \right)\  
    & = \max_{\substack{
              \boldsymbol{a}^{G},\boldsymbol{a}^{L}, \boldsymbol{\beta},\boldsymbol{\gamma}, \\
              \underline{\boldsymbol{\pi}}, \overline{\boldsymbol{\pi}}, \underline{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}, \overline{\boldsymbol{\sigma}}
                        }} 
        \sum_{b \in \mathscr{N}} \beta_{b} \left(D_{b} - \tilde{g}_{b} \right) -
        \sum_{l \in \mathscr{L}} \overline{F}_{l} 
                \left( \underline{\pi}_{l} + \overline{\pi}_{l} \right) +
       &&  \hspace{-0.2em}
                \sum_{i \in \mathscr{I}} 
                \left[ \underline{\sigma}_{i} 
                \left( a_{i}^{G} \left( p_{i} - r_{i}^{D} \right) \right) - \overline{\sigma}_{i} \left( a_{i}^{G} \left( p_{i} + r_{i}^{U} \right) \right) \right]  \\%\label{eq01:LOL_Func_SL} \\
%
    &   \text{subject to:}
        &&   \notag \\ 
%
    &   \beta_{b} + \underline{\sigma}_{i} - \overline{\sigma}_{i} \leq 0,
        &&  \forall ~ b \in \mathscr{N}, i \in \mathscr{I}_{b};
            \label{eq03:LOL_Func_SL}  \\%
%
    &   \beta_{to(l)} - \beta_{fr(l)} + \gamma_{l} + \underline{\pi}_{l} - \overline{\pi}_{l} = 0,
        &&  \forall ~ l \in \mathscr{L};
            \label{eq04:LOL_Func_SL}                               
\end{alignat}
    \end{document}
```